# Angular Break/Pause on Uncaught Exception

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, I would like to be able to break/pause on uncaught exceptions in **my application** but that doesn't seem to work in Angular.  Is that possible?

It looks like **zone.js** catches them and intern logs them to the console so the '[pause on exceptions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/automatically-pause-on-any-exception)' feature doesn't work as they are caught exceptions.

[image: chrome pause screenshot]

---

Example error:

```
VM2031:34 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): UnsupportedAuthorityValidation
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Yes **zone.js** usually catches errors that come out of Angular. You can still open up the source files in chrome and add breakpoints there, but it may be hard since the code being output by Angular/Typescript/(maybe webpack if that is what you are using) is likely different than the code you wrote. 

I would look into adding breakpoints through your IDE, what IDE do you have?

Comment: I'm using VS Code.  And yes, I'm using Webpack.  @TommyMay

Comment: I feel like I would be doing you a disservice by trying to explain something I have not done. I use IntelliJ which supports debugging by using Typescript source maps. This article seems to be the VS Code equivalent https://medium.com/@dupski/debug-typescript-in-vs-code-without-compiling-using-ts-node-9d1f4f9a94a Good Luck!

Comment: Is there a certain event which causes the exceptions to get thrown? E.g. clicking a button.

Comment: @spottedmahn did you find a way to do this?

Comment: unfortunately not  @Skarlinski

Answer (score 0):

How about enabling the **Pause On Caught Exceptions** checkbox?

In general, many people don't realize that DevTools has a lot of different breakpoints that can get triggered in different scenarios. Maybe you can scan the [Breakpoints Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) and see if one of these other breakpoint types will get you close to the issue? If it does, please update your question to explain the problem that you were facing as well as the breakpoint type that you used.

Comment: I've tried that and it breaks on all types of exceptions in libraries.

Comment: Is there a single location that handles caught exceptions? Maybe you could set a [conditional breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#conditional-loc) in the `catch` block so that you only pause on exceptions relevant to your issue.